# Generalized Traveling Salesman Problem in zimpl

Tags: modeling, traveling-salesman, scip

I am new to zimpl and I am currently trying to modell the GTSP. The setting is that we have nodes which are grouped into clusters.
My problem is i dont know how to implement in zimpl which node belongs to which cluster.

What I did so far:

`set V:= {1..6};`
`set A:= {<i,j> in V*V with i < j};` 
`set C:=    {1,2,3};`
`set W:=    {<p,q> in C*C with p < q};`  
`set P[]:= powerset(C);`
`set K:= indexset(P);`

I am guessing something is missing because i want to group node `1,2` in cluster `1`, `3,4` in cluster `2` and `5,6` in cluster `3`.

Maybe someone can help!
thanks

Comment: Hello there,
I'm guessing this can't be the whole code. Can you post the mathematical model that you want to model using ZIMPL?

I'm guessing the cluster-node assignements should be read in from some data-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read in the cluster-city correspondance from a file, there is an extensive section on how to achieve that in the [ZIMPL user guide](https://zimpl.zib.de/download/zimpl.pdf).
I don't think it can read an arbitrary number of entries in a line, though.
So I would instead convert the cluster-part of the GTSP instance file into a list of node-cluster assignments, i.e. (taking the example from [here](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/zvero/GTSPLIB/)):

```
GTSP_SET_SECTION:
1 4 5 -1
2 1 2 3 10 11 12 13 14 -1
3 8 9 17 -1
4 6 7 15 16 -1
```

I would first turn into

```
1 4
1 5
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 10
...
```

Then you could read that in as:

```
members[C] := read "cluster.txt" as "<1n> 2n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an indexed set (just as u did to implement the powerset of `C`) and assign the sets as needed. Try this for example:

```
set Clusters[C]:= <1> {1,2}, <2> {3,4}, <3> {5,6};
```

Use the following line to check your input for correctness:

```
do forall <p> in C do print Clusters[p];
```

This will print

```
List: |1|{<1>,<2>}
List: |1|{<3>,<4>}
List: |1|{<5>,<6>}
```

to the console.